# facebook share button callback by javascript-sdk not working

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm using the Share Button as the document follow: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

```
<div class="fb-share-button" 
        data-href="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
        data-layout="button_count">
</div>
```

I tried to invoke the callback function by using FB.Event.subscribe(), (for e.g **'edge.create'**), as mentioned at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.5
, but it doesn't work. Of course I have initialized facebook javascript-sdk already.

Note: it's working with the Like Button, I can do invoke the callback function for the Like Button successfully.

Any help please!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you previewing your site in a local server? If you aren't, you won't be able to view the buttons.

Comment: Yes, already and it works for the Like button with the 'edge.create' correctly, but for the Share Button, I don't know how to invoke the callback function.

Comment: Got it. Sorry, I don't know either! Facebook API docs drive me mad! Someone experienced will certainly help you. Good luck! :)

Comment: The documentation clearly states that `edge.create` is for like made via the like button only. There is no event for a successful share. The Share _Dialog_ can give you a post id under specific conditions (see docs).

Comment: Yes, thank you for the info. I would switch to the dialog instead.